# What does 了 mean in ...这份工作让我认识到了团队合作的重要?

Tags: grammar, particles

Is it a verb? A past tense maker? Which is its function of 了 in this sentence?

> 曾在新西兰Burger King做过汉堡，当过收银员。这份工作让我认识到了团队合作的重要

Comment: It suggests that the person didn't realise the importance of teamwork before, but after the experience, he realised it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"**verb + 了**" is used to emphasize the **completion** of the action.

So "认识到了" means "I have realized".

Answer (score 1):

认识到了 <- Acknowledged, Learned.

The word "了" means past tense "ed".

Comment: Wrong. It indicates the perfective aspect.. not past tense.

Comment: I disagree to deutschZuid's opinion. 

吃了汉堡
吃汉堡 

Both are already perfected. It clearly stated as past tense.

Comment: @user3019766 吃汉堡 could be used to describe something one does habitually or a general statement, such as "我很喜欢吃汉堡" (an imperfective sentence). Also, perfective can be applied to actions that have not happened yet, e.g., "你吃完了以后，给我打电话".

Comment: You may translate "认识到了" as "have acknowledged" or "acknowledged". It would not matter much in Chinese language. My understanding of Chinese grammar is that there is no such thing as perfective/imperfective sentence. In fact I find past/future/present tenses are not even important enough to be mentioned.I find that people who begins to learn Chinese and caring so much abt grammar extremely frustrating. I'm not a Chinese teacher/educator or anything, but I'm a native speaking Chinese and have 20+ Chinese articles published. I really don't find that very useful to master the grammar.

Comment: "I really don't find that very useful to master the grammar." I think that's something you can say only because you're a native speaker who have already mastered the grammar. It's a little bit like saying that pronunciation isn't important if you pronunciation is already flawless.

Answer (score 0):

You might already know that Chinese does not have a lot of grammatical structure.  But how do Chinese people make a sentence to mean what past tense and perfect tense?
They put a 了 in the sentence (most of the times right after the verb)